# When i am installing Magento 2.0, following errors have occurred. How to solve them?

Tags: magento2

[image: when i installing the latest version of xampp the following error will occured]

When i am installing the Magento 2.0, following errors have occurred.

How  to solve them?

Comment: Are you installing on local or on server?

Comment: Which type of errors are coming ?

Comment: the above image can shows the errors

Comment: @hi satish whether you are going to install in windows or linux

Comment: windows7 ultimate

Answer (score 1):

Please set always_populate_raw_post_data to -1 in your php.ini file.

Also check your 2 php extensions that are not available. please install them. Both will be shown below as they are not shown in image above.

Comment: ok thank you i didn't understand clearly 2 php extensions?

Comment: Let me know which are those two extensions ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PHP 7 instead of 5.6 which is recommended for Magento2.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the php.ini file of your server and uncomment(remove ; semicolon) following extensions:

```
extension=php_intl.dll

extension=php_xsl.dll
```